# MS InTune: Is it possible to get a previous app version from the AppStore?

Tags: app-store, intune

Is it possible to use MS InTune to get a previously listed version of an App that was listed on the Apple App Store? For example, if the current app store version is currently 4.2 but I want to use Ms Intune to install version 4.1 on our devices, is that possible?